# Одеть кого-то в сапоги

Tags: грамотная-речь

Попался на одном из сообществ такой вопрос. Можно в сапоги кого-то обуть, так? А вот, можно ли сказать "одеть кого-то в сапоги"? Вообще, правильно употреблять по отношению к обуви слова "одеть" и "надеть"?
Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Из Ожегова:

ОБУТЬ, 1. кого-что. Надеть обувь. О. сапоги. О. ребенка.

НАДЕТЬ 2. что. Покрыть тело или часть тела какой-н. одеждой.  Н. шубу.  Н.  валенки.  Н. пальто  на ребенка.

ОДЕТЬ 1. кого-что  во что  или чем. Покрыть  кого-н.  какой-н.  одеждой, покрывалом.  О.  ребенка в  пальто.

Таким образом, можно обуть сапоги или  надеть сапоги (на себя), можно обуть ребенка или надеть сапоги ребенку. Варианты "одеть пальто", одеть сапоги" встречаются в речи, но общество по-разному воспринимает их нормативность.